# Why I am not able to replace "/abcd/" to "/xyz/" using string.replaceAll() method

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have a big string which has many url strings, I want to replace context of all urls. for example

`https://host:port/sometext/abc`

i want to replace `/sometext/` with `/newtext/` like this

`mystring.replaceAll("/sometext/", "/newtext/");`

I cant just search `sometext` and replace because `sometext` might have been used at many places.

But its not working even I tried replace method also but its also not working. Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us code please.  (Hint: Java strings are immutable.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, String class is immutable. You can explore this at https://www.javatpoint.com/immutable-string.
The answer for your question is the following code:

```
String mystring = "https://host:port/sometext/abc";

mystring = mystring.replaceAll("/sometext/", "/newtext/");

System.out.println(mystring);
```